# Python | venv won't execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

Using a Windows machine
**Windows PowerShell**
I am trying to creating a virtual env in Python3.
Nothing executes. There is nothing inside the directory `sandbox`
Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.

I've checked `pip list`
[image: pip list]

```
python3 -m venv icon_t1
```

No environment is created

[image: python3 -m venv icon_t1]

Comment: What do you get when you type `dir`?

Comment: nothing. I type `dir` and it just goes to the next line `PS C:\Users\Samson\Desktop\sandbox`

Comment: Take note that _Python_'s [`venv` is a module of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (`python3 -m venv`), and [_virtualenv_](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) is a 3rd party project. They are different things. They achieve similar purposes though. -- Please clarify which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing is wrong in this code. as you can see in this picture I have shown you 2 virtual environment using both CMD and PowerShell.
[image]

notice that if you have just python3 in your system, there is no need to type `python3 -m venv virtualenvname`. in this case you will get this error:

[image]
just use `python -m venv virtualenvname` as I have shown you in the first picture.

but still maybe the best way to create a virtual environment  is to use `virtualenv`, [see the user guide here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html).
just use this code to create the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv virtualenvname
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a virtual environment with the `virtualenv` command:

```
virtualenv icon_t1
```

[`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is a relatively new addition to standard Python. All the examples use a absolute path to the virtual environment directory. Try that and see if it works for you.